# RewriteRule - discard trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP project with a .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/blog/"
RewriteRule "^([^.?/]+)/?$" "index.php?page=$1" [END,QSA]
```

I have a very strange problem with url `localhost/blog/administration`. It's definitely not caused by a PHP file, because happens even with empty source code.

My problem is: when I type `localhost/blog/administration`, the URL in address bar is changed to `localhost/blog/administration/?page=administration`. This doesn't happen after typing `localhost/blog/administration/` (with trailing slash) in the address bar.

What's stranger - given problem happens only with `administration` URL but not with, for example, `home`.

What could be the cause?

DISCLAIMER: Said problem happens even when I use fresh browser (no cache) and index.php with `exit;` at the beggining...

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule "^([^.?/]+)?$" "index.php?page=$1" [END,QSA]`

Comment: @NemanjaJeremic what does it change? The purpose of `/?` was to accept trailing slash but not require it.

Comment: I saw u use `([^.?/]+)` for every possible sign.  I assume u need just letters in your URL.  It's better to use something like this. `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]` .... Also Yes I made a mistake in the first comment. Because I didn't saw **?** in your rewriterule. I think this will help :)

Comment: Trailing slash is added at end of URI if that points to a real directory by `mod_dir` module for security reasons. Don't you have an `index.php` inside `/blog/administration/` directory?

Comment: @anubhava Oh... In fact I have `administration/` directory. And it could be the real cause. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Trailing slash is added at end of URI if that points to a real directory by Apache's `mod_dir` module for security reasons otherwise it may result in directory listing of your directory.

It is advisable to have `index`.php inside your `/blog/administration/` directory to prevent this behavior. Otherwise you can have a separate rule to add trailing rule before final rule:

```
Options FollowSymLinks -Indxes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [END,QSA]
```

---

Also take note of `-Indxes` in options line above to disable directory listing.

Comment: Thanks for an answer but I've decided to disable `DirectorySlash` and `DirectoryIndex` in .htaccess. I'm familiar with security warning in documentation and I'm not planning to use directory indexing.

Comment: Disabling `DirectorySlash` is a security risk but disabling `DirectoryIndex` is good measure. For disabling directory listing `-Indxes` is used (edited answer)